# How to print the text inside of a child tag and the href of a grandchild element with a single BeautifulSoup Object?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a document which contains several `div.inventory` siblings.

```
<div class="inventory">
    <span class="item-number">123</span>
    <span class="cost">
           <a href="http://linktoitem" class="price">$1.23</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I would like to iterate over them to print the item number and link of the item.

```
123 http://linktoitem
456 http://linktoitem2
789 http://linktoitem3
```

How do I parse these two values after selecting the `div.inventory` element?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmlSource = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource)
matches = soup.select('div.inventory')
for match in matches:
    #prints 123
    #prints http://linktoitem
```

Also - what is the difference between the `select` function and `find*` functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find both items using [`find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) relying on the `class` attributes:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for inventory in soup.select('div.inventory'):
    number = inventory.find('span', class_='item-number').text
    link = inventory.find('span', class_='cost').a.get('href')
    print number, link
```

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<body>
    <div class="inventory">
        <span class="item-number">123</span>
        <span class="cost">
               <a href="http://linktoitem" class="price">$1.23</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="inventory">
        <span class="item-number">456</span>
        <span class="cost">
               <a href="http://linktoitem2" class="price">$1.23</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="inventory">
        <span class="item-number">789</span>
        <span class="cost">
               <a href="http://linktoitem3" class="price">$1.23</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for inventory in soup.select('div.inventory'):
    number = inventory.find('span', class_='item-number').text
    link = inventory.find('span', class_='cost').a.get('href')
    print number, link
```

Prints:

```
123 http://linktoitem
456 http://linktoitem2
789 http://linktoitem3
```

Note the use of [`select()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) - this method allows to use `CSS Selectors` for searching over the page. Also note the use of [`class_` argument](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) - underscore is important since `class` is a reversed keyword in Python.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks, I knew you were somewhere around the `bs` tag and was in a hurry :)

Comment: @alexc ty - Any insight into the difference between `select` and `find*`

Comment: @user784637 think about `CSS selectors` as a mini-query-language for searching over the tree, in a way similar to xpath in case you are familiar. Hope that helps.